# how to draw a bar chart and table of data in the same figure like the picture in R?

Tags: r, charts

I want to draw a bar chart including the data as a table like this in R,  but don't know how to do? Thanks in advance.
Note that the category names in x-axis are the column title in the table, and the value of y-axis are the data corresponding to the column.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxDXd.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Here’s a link which may be useful to asking a question that makes it easier for others to help. [Link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)